# Can't select bones to weight paint

Tags: bones, weight-painting

My project:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_1KUvHXVfnsyHzWJ_3ZLTlikJTGfhu5C/view?usp=sharing

[image]

I've rigged this character (thank you @moonboots for the help) and am now trying to adjust the weight painting. I select the Armature in Object Mode, then the mesh I want to adjust, and select Weight Paint mode.

I don't know how to select the bone I want to adjust. Clicking bones doesn't select them and selecting bones in the Outliner doesn't show me the weight of that bone. For instance, in the attached pic, I've selected the wrist controller, but it still shows me the weight paint for seemingly the thumb. How can select individual bones and also see/adjust their weights?

Comment: Use Ctrl-click to select the bone?